# Batch files leaving cmd window opened

Tags: batch-file

i made a batch script to open 6 other batch files at a time.Those 6 batch files are made to open 6 different applications. Here is the script:

```
@echo off
start batch.bat
start batch2.bat
start batch3.bat
start batch4.bat
start batch5.bat
start batch6.bat
```

Now the problem is after opening all the 6 batch files and they run the applications, but leaves 6 cmd windows opened. How can i close them ? (sorry am new to this .. a total noob)

Comment: Do you have exit on each batch file?

Comment: ah no .. i dont have .

Answer (score 1):

How about "exit" command at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You must be more explicit with the `start` command. Try this:

```
@echo off
start "" cmd /c batch.bat
start "" cmd /c batch2.bat
start "" cmd /c batch3.bat
start "" cmd /c batch4.bat
start "" cmd /c batch5.bat
start "" cmd /c batch6.bat
```

Starting `cmd /c` will exit when the batches exit. The first quotes is for a Window name, might be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Use the /b parameter of [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to suppress the creation of new window.

```
start /b batch.bat
start /b batch2.bat
start /b batch3.bat
start /b batch4.bat
start /b batch5.bat
start /b batch6.bat
```